# Macbook Pro 2013 slow startup from sleep since Yosemite

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, sleep-wake

I have an 8GB Macbook Pro (2013) and have recently upgraded from Mavericks to Yosemite. Everything has been fine except when I wake it from sleep. Firstly, it brings up the login screen but the picture and box for my password are disjointed and not in line. When I try typing  my password, the cursor moves but the box remains blank. When I enter my password the screen turns a transparent white and a loading bar fills up at the bottom of the screen before finally allowing me in. Sometimes it even starts a full reboot and I have to wait for a bar to fill up.

This only ever happened in Mavericks if I let my battery die whilst in sleep mode but its doing it all the time since I installed yosemite. Its really annoying as I move around a lot with  my macbook so often put it to sleep so I can wake it readily later.

I can hear my disk start up when I open the lid so I assume its hibernating rather than just sleeping and is dumping my memory to disk?

Any help around this would be appreciated.

ps. Also when running some python recently it decided to go black, fall on its arse and die out of nowhere. It then restarted and complained that it hadn't been shut down properly.

Comment: internal or external monitor or both? how does it work in safe mode? without console log to see what is happening, I would guess you should reinstall Yosemite (cmd-r)

Comment: I tried a clean install but it didn't solve the problem. I was using a hdd so just underestimated how slow it was. I have a SSD now so its no longer a problem