# MBP hanging on unlock after sleep in Yosemite

Tags: macos, sleep-wake

My mid-2012 MacBook Pro is worse at waking up from sleep than I am. I mash some keys to wake it up, enter my password, and it just hangs on the login attempt. There's no crash and no error, like I've seen in many other questions here - it just sits there. I can still hit "cancel" and go back to the Enter Password screen, and the "go back to sleep" function works fine. But attempting another login just results in another hang

This usually happens only after an extended period of sleeping - almost every time it goes overnight, but not when I step away for an hour or so.

It seems to have begun recently when I upgraded to Yosemite.

Comment: I've seen several related questions, but I don't think this duplicates any of them. (Subtle variations on the theme of Yosemite sleep/wake issues.) [This comes close](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/155512/7749) but I'm not seeing any of those weird UI issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set a 24-hour delay before the SSD goes into standby mode:

```
sudo pmset -a standbydelay 86400
```

and my MBP now unlocks just fine after waking up.